# Continuity with restrictions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

Suppose that $f \colon A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function and that $B \subseteq A$. We define the restriction of $f$ to $B$ to be the function  $f|_B B \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_B(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in B$

1. Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $a \in B$ then $f|_B$ is continous there also.
2. Deduce that the restriction of a continuous function to an arbitrary subset of its domain is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $f$ is continuous at $a$, then given $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x \in (a - \delta, a+\delta)$, that is all x that abide with $|x-a| < \delta$ we have  $|f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$ or in other words $$f((a - \delta, a+\delta)) \subseteq (f(a) - \varepsilon, f(a) + \varepsilon)$$ Now just take $(a -\delta, a +\delta) \cap B = \{x |$ $x \in B$ and $|x-a| < \delta\}$ . (Do you see why this works?)

Comment: Is open ball the same thing as open set?

Comment: @Analysisugh What is your definition of open set?

Comment: uh, is there a way to do it without topology, that is just using the continuity definiton

Comment: @Analysisugh what is your continuity definition?

Comment: Epsilon and Delta definition

Comment: @Analysisugh Well thats the one I used, I'll rewrite it to be a more explicit.

Comment: @Analysisugh Do you understand now?