# Prove that the restriction $f\vert_A$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $A\subset S$. Let $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then the restriction $f\vert_A$ is continuous.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? What does a function $f: A \to \mathbb R$ have to satisfy to be continuous?

Comment: Please include some more context. What specific problem do you have? What definition of coninuity do you use?

Comment: I notice that you have not accepted answers to any of your submitted questions. I therefore won't try to answer this one

Comment: @ziggurism That's not entirely relevant, is it?

Comment: @ClementC. I made the comment in the hopes of changing the behavior of the user, for better future participation. I concede it is not relevant to the question at hand. If stackexchange had a message system I would use that instead.

Comment: OP - After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Please don't worry - it looks like you were unaware and ignorance is not a crime, at least on Math.SE.

Comment: @Nitin..mathsstack is the only learn good maths..i am really happy.. most of the my time spend here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Continuity with restrictions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976031/continuity-with-restrictions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of the subspace topology, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space then $\{U\cap A | U\in\tau\}$ are the open sets of $A\subseteq X$. But then if $O$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$ we have that

$$f\big|_A^{-1}(O) = f^{-1}(O)\cap A$$

but since $f$ is continuous, this is the intersection of open sets, hence is itself open, showing the restriction is continuous.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that $f:S\to\mathbb R$ is continuous. This implicates that $S$ and $\mathbb R$ are both equipped with a topology.

---

The restriction can be written as:$$f\circ i_A$$ where $i_A:A\to S$ denotes the inclusion function prescribed by $a\mapsto a$.

If $A\subset S$ is equipped with the subspace topology inherited from $S$ then $i_A$ is continuous, hence composition $f\circ i_A$ is continuous.